# Carry digit/padding in big int addition in C

Tags: c

I am trying to add two big integers input as strings by the user. When the two input strings are of different length, I try to pad the shorter number with zeros but it's not working out. So if I input 456 and 7, it gives 3 preceded by some random characters. 
Thanks for any suggestions!

```
void reverse(char *start, char *end)
    {
        int l ;
        int len = strlen(start);
        for (l=0;l<len;l++)
            end[l] = start[len-l-1];
        end[len] = '\0'; 

    }

    void add (char *x, char *y, char *sum)
    {
        char XA[MAXDIGITS];
        char YA[MAXDIGITS];
        char tempa[MAXDIGITS];
        int xa_len, ya_len, xa1, ya1, carry, addition, p, q;
        int m = 0;
        int n = -1;
        xa_len=strlen(x);
        ya_len=strlen(y);
        reverse(x,XA);
        reverse(y,YA);
        m = (xa_len > ya_len)?xa_len:ya_len;
        for(xa1=0;xa1<=m;xa1++)
            tempa[xa1] = '0';
        tempa[xa1] = '\0';
        if(xa_len>ya_len)
        {
            for(p=(xa_len-ya_len);p=<m;p++) YA[p]='0';
            YA[p] = '\0';
        }
        if(ya_len>xa_len)
        {
            for(q=(xa_len-ya_len);q=<m;q++) XA[q]='0';
            XA[p] = '\0';
        }
        for(xa1=0;xa1<=m;xa1++)
        {   
            addition=(XA[xa1]-'0')+(YA[xa1]-'0')+carry;
            tempa[xa1] = addition%10+'0';
            carry = addition/10;
            if (n<xa1) n=xa1;                           
        }       
        printf("%d", carry);    
        for(;n>0 && tempa[n]=='0';n--)
        tempa[n+1]='\0';
            reverse(tempa,sum); 
    }
```

This is how I am printing my output

```
add (x,y,addition);
        int length=(strlen(addition));
        printf("Sum is ");
        for(k=0;k<length;k++) printf("%c",addition[k]);
```

Comment: I can see a couple places where you use `carry`, but I don't see anywhere that you give `carry` an initial value.  I suggest that you compile with warnings set to maximum.  That's `-Wall` on unix and IIRC `-W4` on microsoft.

Comment: you might want to use this as a reference.
https://github.com/arunmoezhi/BigNumArithmetic

Answer (score 0):

Certainly `carry` must be initialized.

Had trouble following your code.  The calls to `reverse()` could instead be done with simply running the loop in the opposite direction.  Further, it appears the a carry out at the end does not affect the result.  Suggested code follows:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *str_add(const char *a, const char *b) {
  size_t alen = a == NULL ? 0 : strlen(a);
  size_t blen = b == NULL ? 0 : strlen(b);
  if (blen > alen) {
    const char *t = a; a = b; b = t;
    size_t tlen = alen; alen = blen; blen = tlen;
  }
  size_t clen = blen + 1;
  int carry = 0;
  char *c = malloc(clen + 1);  // 1 extra
  const char *ap = &a[alen];
  const char *bp = &b[blen];
  char *cp = &c[clen];
  *cp = '\0';
  while (bp > b) {
    int sum = *(--ap) - '0' + *(--bp) - '0' + carry;
    carry = 0;
    if (sum >= 10) {
      sum -= 10;
      carry++;
    }
    *(--cp) = sum + '0';
  }
  while (ap > a) {
    int sum = *(--ap) - '0' + carry;
    carry = 0;
    if (sum >= 10) {
      sum -= 10;
      carry++;
    }
    *(--cp) = sum + '0';
  }
  if (carry) {
    memmove(&cp[1], &cp[0], clen);
    *cp = carry + '0';
  }
  return cp;
}

void test_add(const char *a, const char *b) {
  char *sum = str_add(a,b);
  printf("%s + %s = %s\n", a, b, sum);
  free(sum);
}
```